# Why can a class not have a static or constant property and an instance property of the same name?

Tags: c#

I've never really questioned this before until now. I've got an input model with a number of fields, I wanted to present the string names of the properties through the input model so that my Grid can use them:

```
public class SomeGridRow
{
    public string Code { get;set; }
    public string Description { get;set; }

    public const string Code = "Code";
}
```

Obviously, this gives the error:

> The type 'SomeGridRow' already
>   contains a definition for 'Code'

Why can the CLR not cope with two properties of the same name which are, in my eyes, separate?

```
string code = gridRow.Code;          // Actual member from instantiated class
string codeField = SomeGridRow.Code; // Static/Const
```

I'm now just using a child class called `Fields` within my inputs now, so I can use `SomeGridRow.Fields.Code`. It's a bit messy, but it works.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because you can also access static (or, non-instance in this case) properties in the same way (inside the same class), and it would be a bit confusing, for example:

```
public class SomeGridRow
{
  public string Code { get;set; }
  public const string Code = "Code";
  public void MyMethod() {
    var thing = Code; //what would this reference?
  }
}
```

Because both this:

```
public class SomeGridRow
{
  public string Code { get;set; }
  public void MyMethod() {
    var thing = Code; //what would this reference?
  }
}
```

And this:

```
public class SomeGridRow
{
  public const string Code = "Code";
  public void MyMethod() {
    var thing = Code; //what would this reference?
  }
}
```

are valid ways to access properties, static or not. It doesn't answer the "why can't I?" question, but more of the why it's not allowed...it would be far too ambiguous IMO.

Comment: Aye, I suppose it's obvious when spelled out like that. I always took static members for granted as being accessed using their actual class name. Part of the coding standards I work to.

Comment: @GenericTypeTea - And that's an excellent standard, inside the class is where it's the most ambiguous I think, perhaps it should never have been allowed this way...but I think the way it ended up is probably the least confusing compromise.

Comment: I agree. It's another case of one size doesn't fit all... It's not a major issue really. I'm just being picky. I just detest nested classes.

Answer (score 3):

It probably could, but the designers of C# wanted to avoid ambiguities that can come from such use (abuse?) of language features.

Such code would end up being confusing and ambiguous to users (did I want the instance or the static method call?, Which one is right?).

Comment: The standards I adhere to always dictate that static members must be referenced by their static name. I.e. `Foo` would always be `TheStaticClass.Foo`. So ambiguity isn't an issue that would affect me. It's a shame really! I would rather have potential (but controlled) ambiguity instead of nested classes.

Comment: @GenericTypeTea - if only MS wrote C# for you and only you ;)

Comment: Well, they should. Visual Studios 2010 GenericTypeTea edition! I'd buy it :)

Comment: @GenericTypeTea - Yeah...but then how do you convince others to install the GTT .Net redistributable? :)

Comment: @Nick Craver - With milk and cookies. Obviously!

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the points already made about ambiguity, i would say that the naming needs to be relooked in such a case.

If two variables / fields having the exact same name in the same context i.e class but different values to me sounds more like a naming issue.

If they are exactly same, you dont need 2 fields.

If they are slightly different, you should have more accurate names.

Comment: instantiatedClass.Code == 'The actual value'. TheClass.Code == 'The name of the field' to pass into the column data source of the grid. I don't like string values sat in the views. The only alternative is to use Lambda expressions and use reflection to get the MethodName.

Comment: @GenericTypeTea - maybe its just my way of doing it but TheClass.Code to me would rather be more accurate as TheClass.CodeColumnName as it stands for the column name and is not to be confused with theObject.Code - which stands for the value in the code column. In this case, i would consider both these variable to be completely different and hence have different names. Atleast to me, having "Code" as the name for them both is misleading. I am afraid i dont quite get the link between the names and how you use them in your lambdas...

Answer (score 0):

In some other languages with a similar syntax, one can access a static member through an instance. So you could access both `string.Empty` and `"abc".Empty`.

C# doesn't allow this (though it does sort of from inside the class or a derived class, in that you can omit the class name for a static member and can omit `this` for an instance member), primarily to avoid confusion (I find it more handy than confusion tbh, but that's just me, I like switch fall-through too so what do I know).

Having introduced a stricter rule to allow for less ambiguity, it would be counterproductive to allow a new looser rule on the back of it that allowed for more. Think how many "why must I use `this` with property X but not property Y?" questions SO would have if it was allowed (we'd have to force `this` with property X to be clear we meant the instance member).